# How do I import Olympus E-PL2 raw files in Lightroom 3.3 for Windows?

Tags: lightroom, raw, windows, adobe-camera-raw, olympus

I want to know how I could import a RAW file from an Olympus E-PL2 to Lightroom 3.3.
If not possible, how I could as least view this in Windows 7 and Vista?

I installed the Raw Codec from Olympus but am still unable to view it properly on Vista (on thumbnail). Is Adobe Camera Raw the solution? I downloaded the Cameraraw 6.3 update but don't know how to update it.

Answer (score 3):

It is now supported in the [LR3.4/ACR6.4 update](http://photoshoplightroombridge.co.uk/2011/05/lightroom-3-4-and-camera-raw-6-4-go-live/).

Along with Canon EOS 600D (Rebel T3i / Kiss X5 Digital),
    Canon EOS 1100D (Rebel T3 / Kiss X50 Digital),
    Fuji FinePix S200 EXR,
    Fuji FinePix F550 EXR,
    Fuji FinePix HS20 EXR,
    Fuji FinePix X100,
    Hasselblad H4D-40,
    Kodak EasyShare Z990,
    Nikon D5100,
    Olympus E-PL1s,
    Olympus XZ-1.

[Windows update](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5022)

[Mac update](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5021)

Comment: It is worth noting that the update is free from any 3.x version of Lightroom.

Answer (score 1):

The E-PL2 is not supported by [Adobe Camera Raw](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/cameraraw.html) prior to version 6.4 (for Lightroom 3.4).

**In order to import raw files for the E-PL2, you should first update to Lightroom 3.4 or later.**

Prior to Lightroom 3.4:
*One workaround is to [change the exif data to show the camera as an E-PL1](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1041&message=37737802&changemode=1), but this may not actually provide perfect support, as it is possible that the format has changed slightly.*

Answer (score 1):

[Capture One](http://www.phaseone.com/en/Software/Capture-One-Pro-6/About/Pro-Overview.aspx) supports the E-PL2 as does [Bibble](http://bibblelabs.com/) though neither are free. Trial versions are available, though, so you can at least test them out. You never know, you may prefer them.

I suspect that your codec isn't working for one of the following:

- Not 64 bit on a 64 bit Windows platform
- E-PL2 format not actually supported

Did you get the codec from the Olympus website or did it come with the camera?